# Track subdomains and query parameters within Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

We have GA on a site that has hundreds of subdomains and each subdomain can have query parameters attached.  I have a filter set up to show full domain and it's as follows...

[image]

Now, when I go to Behavior -> Site Content -> All Pages I see all the subdomain pages that were visted

```
john.male.personfinder.com
stacy.female.personfinder.com
mark.male.personfinder.com
sue.male.personfinder.com
```

What's not being "tracked" (probably the wrong term), is the query parameters that COULD follow the above urls.

```
john.male.personfinder.com
john.male.personfinder.com?state=ca
john.male.personfinder.com?state=ca&city=sf
```

Do I need to set up another filter to track these query parameters?  Google Analytics is like a foreign language to me, so any walkthroughs and explanations would be GREATLY appreciated.  Searching the web gave me mixed answers that didn't quiet match what I was looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to populate a custom dimension from your site, to get the parameter information.

Here's a snippet from my use of something similar:

```
$scoreid = $_GET["scoreid"];
...
<a name="metadata" id="metadata" data-scoreid="<?php echo $scoreid; ?>"></a>
```

I then use the data-scoreid DOM element to populate a custom GA dimension (in my case via a Google Tag Manager variable).